# How do I find the backend generated code in weka?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I am using weka for classification.
If I use Naive Bayes for classification of datasets, how can I see the backend code of the naive bayes algorithm in weka??

Is there any way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka is open source, so you can see their code at [their repository](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/) as stated in [their website](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/svn.html). The naive bayes part is [here](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/branches/stable-3-8/packages/external/hiddenNaiveBayes/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/bayes/HNB.java)